# Capybara RSpec Not Finding and Clicking CSS Element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am writing a test suite for a Rails code base of mine and am trying to click on a search icon using Capybara and check if the search field appears. However, the test keeps failing as Capybara cannot find the CSS element "search_icon". I have tried using `click_on()` and `find(CSS).click`, but neither work. The former returns the error

> 1) Contents search clicking magnifying glass makes search box appear
>        Failure/Error: click_on('search_icon')
>        Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find link or button "search_icon"
>        # ./spec/features/contents/contents_search_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in '

and the latter returns

> 1) Contents search clicking magnifying glass makes search box appear
>        Failure/Error: find('#search_icon').click
>        Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find css "#search_icon"
>        # ./spec/features/contents/contents_search_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in '

This is the RSpec desription

```
scenario "clicking magnifying glass makes search box appear" do
  visit contents_path

  find("#search_icon").click

  #Also tried this:
  #click_on('search_icon')

  expect(find("#search-form").visible?).to be true
end
```

that attempts to find this element

```
<div class="pull-right has-tooltip" data-title="Search" id="search_icon" data-original-title="" title="">

<i class="glyphicons-icon search"></i>

</div>
```

Is there an issue with my RSpec scenario code or how else could I find and click on this element?

Comment: Try `page.find("#search_icon").click`

Comment: On a side note, any time I have something to click, I find it best to make it a button or link. You may want to make the div an `a` element, with the `href='#'`. That way, you can click on the link itself, while the icon is seen as a label, in a way

Comment: All of the solutions have made my code better and more readable, though turns out not the entire issue. Apparently the team changed 'contents_path', causing it to load an error page. One I changed it to the correct path, the current statement worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

#click_on is an alias for #click_link_or_button which will only click  <a href=...> or <button> elements.  Your usage of #find and #click is the correct way to be doing this, however depending on the css you're applying to the actual icon its possible the div actually has a width and/or height of 0px - which will make it unclickable.  Instead try clicking on the actual icon using something like

```
find('#search_icon .search').click
```

also -- your expectation at the end will read better if you use the capybara rspec matchers

```
expect(page).to have_css('#search_form', visible: true)
```

the visible: true is only needed if you have changed Capybaras default of only finding visible elements

Comment: ^ I suggest you add that comment to the answer.